# How do I make it so font-awesome icons have no text decoration?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I seem to be having an issue where font awesome icons are rendering in purple for links that are already clicked. Here is how I set up the HTML:

```
<div class="notxtdec"> 
<a href="https://www.facebook.com"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.notxtdec {
text-align: center;
align-items: center;
font-size: 12px;
text-decoration: none; }
```

Comment: Probably you need to style a.visited and set the color you want for the visited link. This should be happening with all links not only FontAwesome

Comment: I tried that and it works, but why doesn't text-decoration work? It works with other links I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.notxtdec` selects a div, not your link. If you want to set the text-decoration for the hyperlink, you need to do something like this, which targets the anchor tag:

```css
.notxtdec {
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 12px; 
}

.notxtdec a {
    text-decoration: none; 
}
```

`text-decoration` will just remove the underline that most browsers automatically add, so if you're trying to set the link, active, or visited colors, you need to add those rules as well:

```css
/* anchor tags which have a valid href attribute */
.notxtdec a:link {
    color: #yourcolorhere
}

/* anchor tags which are being pressed/clicked */
.notxtdec a:active {
    color: #yourcolorhere
}

/* anchor tags which have an href which exists in the browser's history */
.notxtdec a:visited {
    color: #yourcolorhere
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp) can help you.

If you add something like this to your css file, it will always stay the same color even if you click on this link before.

```
a:link {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```